# JSONata bit-manipulation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, jsonata

Is it possible to do somehow bit manipulation on integers in JSONata?

& is concatenation operator, and I didn't find anything about bit manipulation in docs(shifting, bitwise logical operation)
I would like to achieve C-type manipulation somehow. e.g.: a=0x10 & 0xEF where a should be 0x00 after evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are no "out of the box" bit manipulation functions available in JSONata, but you can [extend JSONata](https://docs.jsonata.org/embedding-extending) by providing  your own.  For example:

Excerpt from [Github Discussion about random values/UUIDs](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/390#issuecomment-556369935):

```
(
  $binPad:=function($n, $len){$pad($formatBase($n,2),-$len,'0')};
  $bitwise:=function($lb, $rb, $fn){$split($lb,'')~>$map(function($c, $i){$fn($c='1',$substring($rb,$i,1)='1')?$power(2,(7-$i)):0})~>$sum()};
  $and:=function($l,$r){$bitwise($binPad($l,8),$binPad($r,8),function($1,$2){$1 and $2})};
  $or:=function($l,$r){$bitwise($binPad($l,8),$binPad($r,8),function($1,$2){$1 or $2})};

  ...

)
```

***Full disclosure: I did not write these functions, but I had seen this used in other scenarios and I am merely suggesting this as an option to the OP.***

Comment: thanks a lot. so strange, that there are no out of the box solution.